# jquery sortable script - get drag item id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I'm using jquery sortable script (drag&drop)

I have 2 questions:

1. how do i get the drag item ID ?
2. after drooping the item i would like to run ajax that will insert the new item to my DB and also get the items order (from top to bottom) so i could save their order. how do i get the items id list in array?

Jquery script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( ".dropZone" ).sortable({
            revert: true,
            stop: function (event, ui) {
                var basketID = event.target.id;
                itemID = ??? 

                alert ("itemID: " + itemID + " go to basketID: " + basketID);

            }
        });

        $( ".attrac" ).draggable({
            connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
            helper: "clone",
            revert: "invalid"
        });

    } );

</script>
```

My html

```
<div class="col-md-5 row mt20">

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" id="item3" >
        <div class="panel-heading">The Tower</div>
        <div class="panel-body">most well-known national heritage sites</div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" id="item4" >
        <div class="panel-heading">Masada</div>
        <div class="panel-body">This Herodian fortification o</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row"></div>

<div class="col-md-5 dropZone" id="basket1" >

</div>

<div class="col-md-5 dropZone" id="basket2"  >

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the already available events and methods of jQuery UIs sortable:

[receive](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive): Will be triggered as soon as your sortable receives an item from the connected draggable. The `ui` parameter contains the dragged element.

[serialize](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize): Will serialize all contained item IDs of the sortable. Note: I added a data attribute as the ID from the draggable element will not be copied to the sortable.

```js
$(".dropZone").sortable({
  revert: true,
  receive: function(event, ui) {
    var basketID = event.target.id;
    var itemID = ui.item[0].id;

    //console.log("itemID: " + itemID + " go to basketID: " + basketID);

    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {
      attribute: "data-id"
    });
    //console.log(data);
    //do ajax call with data
  },
  update: function(event, ui) {
    var basketID = event.target.id;
    var itemID = ui.item.data('id');
    var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {
      attribute: "data-id"
    });
    data = data + '&basketID=' + basketID;
    console.log("itemID: " + itemID + " go to basketID: " + basketID);
    console.log(data);
    $.post("url/to/serverside", function(data) {
      //result callback
    });
  }
});

$(".attrac").draggable({
  connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
  helper: "clone",
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-5 row mt20">

  <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" id="item3" data-id="item_3">
    <div class="panel-heading">The Tower</div>
    <div class="panel-body">most well-known national heritage sites</div>
  </div>

  <div class="panel panel-info attrac ui-widget-content" id="item4" data-id="item_4">
    <div class="panel-heading">Masada</div>
    <div class="panel-body">This Herodian fortification o</div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="row"></div>

<div class="col-md-5 dropZone" id="basket1">
  drop here
</div>

<div class="col-md-5 dropZone" id="basket2">
  drop here
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code works only on "receive" event and not on "stop", and it's hard when i'm doing sorting inside the bascket....

Comment: @Roi see my updated answer, I added the `update` event which I would recommend using over the `stop` event (stop fires every time, update only if the sort order actually changes)

Comment: thank you for your effort. I just want to be sure - although your wrote 3 console lines i see only 2 lines (the "serialize") is not display...

Comment: and one more thing - how do i send all the items id + dropZone id to ajax file?

Comment: @Roi I cleaned up the code a bit, should be clearer now. The ´data´  can be submitted directly via ajax as the data parameter. The dropzone ID can be added to the variable as a normal URL parameter

Comment: empiric -- why do i need the "receive" part? can i use only "update" ?

Comment: @Roi yes you could depending on when you want to update and how often. If you only want to update as soon a new item is dragged in you can use `receive`, if you want to update every time something changes use  `update`

Comment: I update my code according yours, and the second console contain only the last var: `&basketID=basket2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173320/discussion-between-roi-and-empiric).

Comment: Oh, i changed the `data-id="attrac4"` to `data-id="attrac_4"` and it's works....strange. not sure why did works...

Answer (score 0):

**How do i get the drag item ID ?**

One way is to have have a wrapper over your content widgets like

```
<div class="panel panel-info attrac" >
        <div class = "panel-content" id ="item3">
        <div class="panel-heading">The Tower</div>
        <div class="panel-body">most well-known national heritage sites</div></div>
</div>
...
var itemID = $(ui.item).find('.panel-content').attr('id');
```

**How to get itemIDs for storing via AJAX?**

```
var itemIDs = [];

$('.dropZone .panel-content').each(function(id, el) {                                                                        
      itemIDs.push($(el).attr('id'));
})
```

Please check this fiddle for full implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/yeshas93/pk47nygx/19/

**Warning**
The following implementation uses jQuery. It also accesses DOM directly every time an item is dropped. Please treat this as a learning opportunity. This should not be used in production unless your application depends solely on jQuery. I would recommended trying out React DND (https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd) for accomplishing the same.

Comment: Thank you! can you use ".attrac" for `var itemID = $(ui.item).find('.panel-content').attr('id');` in my original code?

Comment: No you can't use same class for draggable div and its children both. It's not good practice. Leads to confusion down the lane. If you want to use 'attrac' for content, use 'attrac-container' or something like that for its parent. Have updated fiddle for same

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/gKXBre

As need to get parent id, you can't get directly in **ui** or **event** but you can get class so add same class and get the id.

```
$(function() {
    $(".dropZone").sortable({
        revert: true,
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            var basketID = event.target.id;
            var cls = $(ui.item).attr('class').split(" ");
            var matches = $(cls)
                .filter(function(i, s) {
                    return (s.indexOf('attrac') !== -1) ? s : '';
                });
            itemID = $('.' + matches[0]).attr('id');

            alert("itemID: " + itemID + " go to basketID: " + basketID);

        }
    });

    $("div[class*='attrac']").draggable({
        connectToSortable: ".dropZone",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid"
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using class ".attrac". can you use t instead?